# Ssh from docker container running as gitlab runner

Tags: docker, ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab

I got a weird problem. I am using a **docker contdainer** runner with **Gitlab** ce to do our builds anywhere. One thing I need to do is to **Scp** results to a central server. The user id, private and public keys are the same on the remote server as the container and I have the remote server as a known host and the public key in the authorised keys file on the server.
Now if I spin up this container stand alone, I can ssh to the remote server. However, when I’m running as a docker container runner on gitlab, it can’t see the remote server. 
I know I’m missing something simple but can’t figure it out. 
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more specific and clarify what you mean by "it can’t see the remote server"? Is there specific error in the container + do you by chance have IP-restricted ssh access to your remote server (check your cloud provider security group)?

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be a sync problem where we pass the ssh keys in to gitlab via variables and write them into ~/.ssh
We have a a group set of variables on gitlab and a project one, which had older keys and thats what caused ssh to fail.